# Help with Minecraft plugin replacing default tp

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

As the title states, I am having trouble with entity teleporting in Minecraft. I know that I am doing it correct as it works in singleplayer, so I figured it would be a plugin that is stopping me from teleporting entities. The command I am using is `/tp @e[name=o] ~ ~300 ~`, and the plugins on my server are:

> AsyncWorldEditInjector, WorldEdit, Installer, VoxelSniper, Skript,
>   CustomServerMessages, Buycraft, ColoredSigns, Vault, Multiverse-Core,
>   PermissionsEx, EmptyWorldGenerator, WorldGuard, Tablist, CoreProtect,
>   ItemRenamer, BuycraftAnnouncer, NoLeafDecay, WildSkript, ProtocolLib,
>   HolographicDisplays, mcMMO, VoidWorld, Essentials, ArmorStandEditor,
>   AsyncWorldEdit, EssentialsProtect, AuctionHouse, EssentialsSpawn,
>   EssentialsGeoIP, WirelessRedstone, EssentialsAntiBuild,
>   FakePlayersOnline, TitleManager, CraftBook, EssentialsChat

If you know how to fix this or what plugins to remove/disable please inform me. Thanks.

Comment: Does your teleport command work in vanilla?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Essentials. I had the same problem on my server, just do:

`/minecraft:tp @e[name=o] ~ ~300 ~`

Answer (score -1):

Use `/setworldspawn` for the world's spawn point